Deleted Item from Room Database Reloads after app restart
So i have a recyclerview with few items(meals) where a user adds from a alertdialog. When I start the app and add a meal then immediately delete it and quit the app , when starting it second time the meal i just added is loaded from the database and it was not deleted , while it must be. When i delete it the second time when it was added previously it gets deleted and not loaded again.
This is my AppDatabase.class:
@Database(entities = {FoodItem.class, FoodMenuItem.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract FoodItemDao foodItemDao();
    public abstract FoodMenuItemDao foodMenuItemDao();
    private static AppDatabase INSTANCE;

    public static AppDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        if(INSTANCE == null){
            INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, "DB_NAME")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}

This is my FoodItem.class
@Entity
public class FoodItem {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int id;
    public String mealName;
    public double kcal;
    public double fats;
    public double proteins;
    public double carbs;
    public String date;
    public int quantity;

    public FoodItem(String mealName, double kcal, double fats, double carbs, double proteins, String date) {
        this.mealName = mealName;
        this.kcal = kcal;
        this.fats = fats;
        this.carbs = carbs;
        this.proteins = proteins;
        this.date = date;
        this.quantity = 100;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getMealName() {
        return mealName;
    }

    public double getKcal() {
        return kcal;
    }

    public double getFats() {
        return fats;
    }

    public double getProteins() {
        return proteins;
    }

    public double getCarbs() {
        return carbs;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setMealName(String mealName) {
        this.mealName = mealName;
    }

    public void setKcal(double kcal) {
        this.kcal = kcal;
    }

    public void setFats(double fats) {
        this.fats = fats;
    }

    public void setProteins(double proteins) {
        this.proteins = proteins;
    }

    public void setCarbs(double carbs) {
        this.carbs = carbs;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }
}

These are few methods from the MealAdapter.class :
public void addMeal(FoodItem meal) {
        meals.add(meal);
        notifyItemInserted(meals.size() - 1);
    }
    public List<FoodItem> getMeals() {
        return meals;
    }
public MealAdapter(List<FoodItem> meals) {
        this.meals = meals;
    }
    public FoodItem getMealAt(int position) {
        return meals.get(position);
    }

    public void removeMeal(FoodItem foodItem) {
        int position = meals.indexOf(foodItem);
        if (position != -1) {
            meals.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
        }
    }

This is my FoodItemDao :
@Dao
public interface FoodItemDao {
    @Insert
    void insert(FoodItem foodItem);
    @Query("SELECT * FROM FoodItem")
    List<FoodItem> getAllMeals();
    @Query("SELECT * FROM FoodItem")
    FoodItem getMeal();
    @Delete
    void delete(FoodItem foodItem);
    @Query("SELECT * FROM FoodItem WHERE date = :date")
    List<FoodItem> getMealsByDate(String date);
    @Query("DELETE FROM FoodItem WHERE date = :date")
    void deleteMealsByDate(String date);
}

This is my Activity :
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_macros_calculator);

db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(),
                AppDatabase.class, "DB_NAME").allowMainThreadQueries().build();
        foodMenuItemDao = db.foodMenuItemDao();
        foodItemDao = db.foodItemDao();

List<FoodItem> savedMeals = loadTodaysMealsFromDatabase();
        for (FoodItem meal : savedMeals) {
            mealAdapter.addMeal(meal);
        }
        updateTotalValues();
    }

private List<FoodItem> loadTodaysMealsFromDatabase() {
        String currentDate = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
        List<FoodItem> meals = foodItemDao.getMealsByDate(currentDate);
        Log.d("Database", "Loaded meals: " + meals.size());
        return meals;
    }

private class SwipeToDeleteCallback extends ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback {
        SwipeToDeleteCallback() {
            super(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
            FoodItem deletedMeal = mealAdapter.getMeals().get(position);
            deleteItem(deletedMeal);
            updateTotalValues();


        }
    }

 private void deleteItem(FoodItem foodItem) {
        AppDatabase database = AppDatabase.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext());
        database.foodItemDao().delete(foodItem);
        Log.d("Database", "Deleted meal: " + foodItem.getMealName());
        mealAdapter.removeMeal(foodItem);
        mealAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        updateTotalValues();
}

........
builder.setPositiveButton("Add", (dialog, which) -> {
                    int selectedQuantity = getSelectedQuantity(radioGroupQuantities);
                    FoodMenuItem selectedMeal = menuAdapter.getSelectedMeal();
                    if (selectedMeal != null && selectedQuantity > 0) {
                        String currentDate = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
                        FoodItem mealToAdd = calculateMealForQuantity(selectedMeal, selectedQuantity);
                        mealToAdd.setDate(currentDate);

                                    foodItemDao.insert(mealToAdd);

                                mealAdapter.addMeal(mealToAdd);
                                updateTotalValues();

                    }

private void updateTotalValues() {
        List<FoodItem> meals = mealAdapter.getMeals(); // Get the list of meals from the adapter
        int totalKcal = 0;
        double totalFats = 0;
        double totalCarbs = 0;
        double totalProteins = 0;

        for (FoodItem meal : meals) {
            totalKcal += meal.getKcal();
            totalFats += meal.getFats();
            totalCarbs += meal.getCarbs();
            totalProteins += meal.getProteins();
        }

        // Update the TextView with the total values
        txtViewTotal.setText("Total - " + totalKcal + "kcal " +
                totalFats + "g fats " +
                totalCarbs + "g carbs " +
                totalProteins +"g proteins");
    }


it seems the first delete removes the item from the meal and the second delete removes the item from the menu

@PerdiEstaquel the removeMeal is the deletion of the recyclerview , the database.foodItemDao().delete(foodItem) should delete from the database. I first delete from the database and then delete from the recyclerview and update the UI ..
